# If I wrote a manual, the language and instructions in it would be easy to follow and understand. - is this acceptable?

Tags: conditionals

**Example 1**

> If I caught COVID-19, the symptoms would be very severe.

The symptoms here are only imaginary. They do not exist unless the condition is met. So, can I write like Example 1? Is the example correct?

**Example 2**

> If I wrote a manual, the language and instructions in it would be easy to follow and understand.

The language and instructions here are only imaginary. They do not exist unless the condition is met. So, can I write like Example 2?
Is the example correct?

Comment: You are asking us to proofread your sentences. [That is generally off-topic here.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) If you have a specific concern (for example, a grammar rule that you are wondering about), then please indicate it.

Comment: "understand and follow" would be better as you normally put these things in chronological order (first you understand the instructions then you follow them). But are you concerned about the conditional?